# Dynamically Clone DIV based on Select Element

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a form in which users will be adding passengers to a manifest. Dependent upon how many people may be on a flight, will decide how many DIV's will be displayed to the user (selected from a `select` element). Sadly, I have browser forums for a few weeks, and tried multiple different ways and adaptations with no avail. Any suggestions?

HTML (add_book.php):

```
    <?php 

$status = $data[status];
$hls_num = $data[hls_num];
$hls_id = $data[hls_id];
$hls_name = $data[hls_name];

?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var pack_prices = new Array();
 <?php 
 $get_packprice  = "SELECT * FROM heli_type WHERE type_status = 'active' ORDER BY type_name";
 $packprice = mysql_query("$get_packprice");
 if ($price = mysql_fetch_array($packprice)) {
     do {
         if ($price[type_status] == 'active') {?>
          pack_prices["<?php echo $price[type_id];?>"]=<?php echo $price[type_cost]?>;
 <?php 
     } else {
 }
 } while ($price = mysql_fetch_array($packprice));
 }
 ?>

 var num_pass = new Array();
 num_pass["1"]=1;
 num_pass["2"]=2;
 num_pass["3"]=3;
 num_pass["4"]=4;
 num_pass["5"]=5;
 num_pass["6"]=6;

function getPackPrice()
{
    var startPackPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["book"];
     var selectedPack = theForm.elements["bookpack"];
    startPackPrice = pack_prices[bookpack.value];
    return startPackPrice;
}

function getNumPass()
{
    var amountOfPass=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["book"];
     var selectedPass = theForm.elements["numpass"];
    amountOfPass = num_pass[numpass.value];
    return amountOfPass;
}

function calculateTotal()
{
    var PackPrice = getPackPrice() * getNumPass();
    var divobj = document.getElementById('baseamount').value = "$"+PackPrice;
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "$"+PackPrice;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('baseamount');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}

function populate(s1,s2){
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1)
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2)

    s2.innerHTML = "";
    if(s1.value == "airwork") {
        var optionArray = ["|--- Please Select Type of Airwork ---",
        <?php $get_airworkTypes = "SELECT * FROM heli_type WHERE type_cat = 'airwork' ORDER BY type_name";
$airworkTypes = mysql_query("$get_airworkTypes");
if ($airwork = mysql_fetch_array($airworkTypes)) {
    do {
        if ($airwork[type_status] == 'Active') {
            echo '"' .$airwork[type_id]. '|' .$airwork[type_name].'",';
                } else {
    } 
    } while ($airwork = mysql_fetch_array($airworkTypes));

}?>];
    }
    if(s1.value == "charter") {
        var optionArray = ["|--- Please Select Type of Charter ---",
        <?php $get_charterTypes = "SELECT * FROM heli_type WHERE type_cat = 'charter' ORDER BY type_name";
$charterTypes = mysql_query("$get_charterTypes");
if ($charter = mysql_fetch_array($charterTypes)) {
    do {
        if ($charter[type_status] == 'Active') {
            echo '"' .$charter[type_id]. '|' .$charter[type_name].'",';
                } else {
    } 
    } while ($charter = mysql_fetch_array($charterTypes));

}?>];
    }
    if(s1.value == "wedding") {
        var optionArray = ["|--- Please Select Wedding Package ---",
        <?php $get_weddingTypes = "SELECT * FROM heli_type WHERE type_cat = 'wedding' ORDER BY type_name";
$weddingTypes = mysql_query("$get_weddingTypes");
if ($wedding = mysql_fetch_array($weddingTypes)) {
    do {
        if ($wedding[type_status] == 'Active') {
            echo '"' .$wedding[type_id]. '|' .$wedding[type_name].'",';
                } else {
    } 
    } while ($wedding = mysql_fetch_array($weddingTypes));

}?>];
    }
    if(s1.value == "scenic") {
        var optionArray = ["|--- Please Select Duration of Scenic Flight ---",
        <?php $get_scenicTypes = "SELECT * FROM heli_type WHERE type_cat = 'scenic' ORDER BY type_name";
$scenicTypes = mysql_query("$get_scenicTypes");
if ($scenic = mysql_fetch_array($scenicTypes)) {
    do {
        if ($scenic[type_status] == 'Active') {
            echo '"' .$scenic[type_id]. '|' .$scenic[type_name].'",';
                } else {
    } 
    } while ($scenic = mysql_fetch_array($scenicTypes));

}?>];
    }
        if(s1.value == "specscen") {
        var optionArray = ["|--- Please Select Duration of Scenic Flight ---",
        <?php $get_specscenTypes = "SELECT * FROM heli_type WHERE type_cat = 'specscen' ORDER BY type_name";
$specscenTypes = mysql_query("$get_specscenTypes");
if ($specscen = mysql_fetch_array($specscenTypes)) {
    do {
        if ($specscen[type_status] == 'Active') {
            echo '"' .$specscen[type_id]. '|' .$specscen[type_name].'",';
                } else {
    } 
    } while ($specscen = mysql_fetch_array($specscenTypes));

}?>];
    }
    if(s1.value == "package") {
        var optionArray = ["|--- Please Select a Package ---",
        <?php $get_packs = "SELECT * FROM heli_type WHERE type_cat = 'package' ORDER BY type_name";
$packs = mysql_query("$get_packs");
if ($pack = mysql_fetch_array($packs)) {
    do {
        if ($pack[type_status] == 'Active') {
            echo '"' .$pack[type_id]. '|' .$pack[type_name].'",';
                } else {
    } 
    } while ($pack = mysql_fetch_array($packs));

}?>
];
    }
        if(s1.value == "discpack") {
        var optionArray = ["|--- Please Select a Package ---",
        <?php $get_packdiscTypes = "SELECT * FROM heli_type WHERE type_cat = 'discpack' ORDER BY type_name";
$packdiscTypes = mysql_query("$get_packdiscTypes");
if ($packdisc = mysql_fetch_array($packdiscTypes)) {
    do {
        if ($packdisc[type_status] == 'Active') {
            echo '"' .$packdisc[type_id]. '|' .$packdisc[type_name].'",';
                } else {
    } 
    } while ($packdisc = mysql_fetch_array($packdiscTypes));

}?>];
    }
    if(s1.value == "specpack") {
        var optionArray = ["|--- Please Select a Package ---",
        <?php $get_packspecTypes = "SELECT * FROM heli_type WHERE type_cat = 'specpack' ORDER BY type_name";
$packspecTypes = mysql_query("$get_packspecTypes");
if ($specdisc = mysql_fetch_array($packspecTypes)) {
    do {
        if ($packspec[type_status] == 'Active') {
            echo '"' .$packspec[type_id]. '|' .$packspec[type_name].'",';
                } else {
    } 
    } while ($packspec = mysql_fetch_array($packspecTypes));

}?>];
    }

    for(var option in optionArray) {
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        s2.options.add(newOption);
    }
}

function cpyDIV(val)
{
    $("#repeat").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < val -1; i++) {
        $("#passenger").clone().appendTo("#repeat");
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="form_contain">

<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span> - Required Fields<br />
<br />
<span style="color:#FF0000">!!!</span> - <i>For bookings with over 6 passengers, please create booking through the Events Page</i><br />
<br />

<form action="?page=book_add" method="post" name="add_booking" id="book" target="_self" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form_head">Booking Details</div>
<br />
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">

<tr>
<td class="form_label">Booking Type</td>
<td colspan="2"><select name="book_cat" id="booktype" class="form_d" onchange="populate(this.id,'bookpack')">
<option value="nothing">--- Select a Catergory ---</option>
<option value="airwork">Air Work</option>
<option value="charter">Charter</option>
<option value="wedding">Wedding Flights</option>
<option value="scenic">Scenic Flight</option>
<option value="specscen">Special Scenic Flight</option>
<option value="package">Packages</option>
<option value="discpack">Packages --- Red Balloon/Adrenalin</option>
<option value="specpack">Packages --- Specials</option>
</select></td>
</tr>

<div id="sub" class="sub">
<tr>
<td></td>
<td colspan="3" class="form_label">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;----> <select class="form_d" id="bookpack" name="book_type" onchange="calculateTotal()"></select></td>
</tr>
</div>

<tr>
<td class="form_label">Pick Up - Location</td>
<td><select class="form_c" name="book_pu_loc">
<option selected="selected">--- Select Location ---</option>
<?php $get_query = ("SELECT * FROM heli_hls WHERE status = 'Active' ORDER BY hls_name");
$query = mysql_query("$get_query");
if ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    do {
        if ($data[status] == "Active") {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data[hls_num] ?>"><?php echo $data[hls_name]?></option>
        <?php } else { 
        }
    } while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query));
}
?>
</select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="form_label">Pick Up - Date</td>
<td><input name="book_date" class="form_f" type="date" required="required"/></td>
<td class="form_label">Pick Up - Time</td>
<td><input name="book_time" class="form_e" type="time" required="required"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="form_label">Passengers</td>
<td valign="middle">

<select id="numpass" name="numpass" class="form_e" onchange="cpyDIV(this.value); getValue();"/>
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>

</table>

<div class="form_head">Payment Details</div>

<table width="100%">

<tr>
<td>

<table width="100%">
<tr><td class="form_label">Type: </td><td><select class="form_b" name="pay_type">
<option value="NULL">--- Payment Method ---</option>
<option value="cash">Cash</option>
<option value="eft">EFTPOS</option>
<option value="mstr">Mastercard</option>
<option value="visa">Visa</option>
<option value="amex">American Express</option>
<option value="house">House Voucher</option>
<option value="vouch">Gift Voucher</option>
<option value="inv">Invoice</option>
<option value="red">Red Balloon</option>
<option value="adren">Adrenalin</option>
<option value="promo">Promotional</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select></td></tr>

<tr><td class="form_label">Payee Name:</td><td><input class="form_b" id="payee" name="payee"/></td></tr>
<tr><td class="form_label">Discount:</td><td><input class="form_a" name="paydisc" id="paydisc" onchange="getValue()"/></td></tr>
<!--<tr><td class="form_label">Total Amount:</td><td><input class="form_i" name="payamount" id="payamount" readonly="readonly" onchange="getValue()"/></td></tr>
--></table>

</td>
<td>

<table width="100%">
<tr><td class="form_label">Base Amount:</td><td><input type="text" name="baseamount" id="baseamount" class="form_i" readonly="readonly" onchange="getValue()"/></td></tr>
<tr><td class="form_label"> - Extra (Pick Up):</td><td><input type="text" name="extrapick" id="extrapick" class="form_e" onchange="getValue()"/></td></tr>
<tr><td class="form_label"> - Extra (Other):</td><td><input type="text" name="extraother" id="extraother" class="form_e" onchange="getValue()"/></td></tr>
<tr><td class="form_label"></td><td></td></tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>

</table>

<div id="passenger" class="passenger">
<div class="form_head">Passenger - Details</div>
<br />
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">

<tr>
<td class="form_label">First Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_fname[]" class="form_f" required="required"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Last Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_lname[]" class="form_f" required="required"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Weight (kg):&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_kg[]" class="form_a" required="required"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="form_label">Phone:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_phone[]" class="form_g" required="required"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Email:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_email[]" class="form_d" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">
<tr><td class="form_label">Address:</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="form_label">Number:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_addr_num[]" class="form_a" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Street:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_addr_street[]" class="form_b" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Suburb/Town:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_addr_sub[]" class="form_f" /></td></tr>
<tr><td class="form_label">State:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_addr_state[]" class="form_b" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Postcode:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_addr_post[]" class="form_a" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Country:&nbsp;<select class="form_c" name="cust_addr_country[]">
<option value="">--- Select Country ---</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option><option value="Akrotiri">Akrotiri</option><option value="Albania">Albania</option><option value="Algeria">Algeria</option><option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option><option value="Andorra">Andorra</option><option value="Angola">Angola</option><option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option><option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option><option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option><option value="Argentina">Argentina</option><option value="Armenia">Armenia</option><option value="Aruba">Aruba</option><option value="Ashmore and Cartier Islands">Ashmore and Cartier Islands</option><option value="Austria">Austria</option><option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option><option value="Bahamas, The">Bahamas, The</option><option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option><option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option><option value="Barbados">Barbados</option><option value="Bassas da India">Bassas da India</option><option value="Belarus">Belarus</option><option value="Belgium">Belgium</option><option value="Belize">Belize</option><option value="Benin">Benin</option><option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option><option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option><option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option><option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option><option value="Botswana">Botswana</option><option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option><option value="Brazil">Brazil</option><option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option><option value="British Virgin Islands">British Virgin Islands</option><option value="Brunei">Brunei</option><option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option><option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option><option value="Burma">Burma</option><option value="Burundi">Burundi</option><option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option><option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option><option value="Canada">Canada</option><option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option><option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option><option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option><option value="Chad">Chad</option><option value="Chile">Chile</option><option value="China">China</option><option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option><option value="Clipperton Island">Clipperton Island</option><option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option><option value="Colombia">Colombia</option><option value="Comoros">Comoros</option><option value="Congo, Democratic Republic of the">Congo, Democratic Republic of the</option><option value="Congo, Republic of the">Congo, Republic of the</option><option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option><option value="Coral Sea Islands">Coral Sea Islands</option><option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option><option value="Cote d'Ivoire">Cote d'Ivoire</option><option value="Croatia">Croatia</option><option value="Cuba">Cuba</option><option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option><option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option><option value="Denmark">Denmark</option><option value="Dhekelia">Dhekelia</option><option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option><option value="Dominica">Dominica</option><option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option><option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option><option value="Egypt">Egypt</option><option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option><option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option><option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option><option value="Estonia">Estonia</option><option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option><option value="Europa Island">Europa Island</option><option value="Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)</option><option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option><option value="Fiji">Fiji</option><option value="Finland">Finland</option><option value="France">France</option><option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option><option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option><option value="French Southern and Antarctic Lands">French Southern and Antarctic Lands</option><option value="Gabon">Gabon</option><option value="Gambia, The">Gambia, The</option><option value="Gaza Strip">Gaza Strip</option><option value="Georgia">Georgia</option><option value="Germany">Germany</option><option value="Ghana">Ghana</option><option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option><option value="Glorioso Islands">Glorioso Islands</option><option value="Greece">Greece</option><option value="Greenland">Greenland</option><option value="Grenada">Grenada</option><option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option><option value="Guam">Guam</option><option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option><option value="Guernsey">Guernsey</option><option value="Guinea">Guinea</option><option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option><option value="Guyana">Guyana</option><option value="Haiti">Haiti</option><option value="Heard Island and McDonald Islands">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option><option value="Holy See (Vatican City)">Holy See (Vatican City)</option><option value="Honduras">Honduras</option><option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option><option value="Hungary">Hungary</option><option value="Iceland">Iceland</option><option value="India">India</option><option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option><option value="Iran">Iran</option><option value="Iraq">Iraq</option><option value="Ireland">Ireland</option><option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option><option value="Israel">Israel</option><option value="Italy">Italy</option><option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option><option value="Jan Mayen">Jan Mayen</option><option value="Japan">Japan</option><option value="Jersey">Jersey</option><option value="Jordan">Jordan</option><option value="Juan de Nova Island">Juan de Nova Island</option><option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option><option value="Kenya">Kenya</option><option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option><option value="Korea, North">Korea, North</option><option value="Korea, South">Korea, South</option><option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option><option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option><option value="Laos">Laos</option><option value="Latvia">Latvia</option><option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option><option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option><option value="Liberia">Liberia</option><option value="Libya">Libya</option><option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option><option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option><option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option><option value="Macau">Macau</option><option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option><option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option><option value="Malawi">Malawi</option><option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option><option value="Maldives">Maldives</option><option value="Mali">Mali</option><option value="Malta">Malta</option><option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option><option value="Martinique">Martinique</option><option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option><option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option><option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option><option value="Mexico">Mexico</option><option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option><option value="Moldova">Moldova</option><option value="Monaco">Monaco</option><option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option><option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option><option value="Morocco">Morocco</option><option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option><option value="Namibia">Namibia</option><option value="Nauru">Nauru</option><option value="Navassa Island">Navassa Island</option><option value="Nepal">Nepal</option><option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option><option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option><option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option><option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option><option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option><option value="Niger">Niger</option><option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option><option value="Niue">Niue</option><option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option><option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option><option value="Norway">Norway</option><option value="Oman">Oman</option><option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option><option value="Palau">Palau</option><option value="Panama">Panama</option><option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option><option value="Paracel Islands">Paracel Islands</option><option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option><option value="Peru">Peru</option><option value="Philippines">Philippines</option><option value="Pitcairn Islands">Pitcairn Islands</option><option value="Poland">Poland</option><option value="Portugal">Portugal</option><option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option><option value="Qatar">Qatar</option><option value="Reunion">Reunion</option><option value="Romania">Romania</option><option value="Russia">Russia</option><option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option><option value="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option><option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option><option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option><option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option><option value="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option><option value="Samoa">Samoa</option><option value="San Marino">San Marino</option><option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option><option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option><option value="Senegal">Senegal</option><option value="Serbia and Montenegro">Serbia and Montenegro</option><option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option><option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option><option value="Singapore">Singapore</option><option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option><option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option><option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option><option value="Somalia">Somalia</option><option value="South Africa">South Africa</option><option value="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option><option value="Spain">Spain</option><option value="Spratly Islands">Spratly Islands</option><option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option><option value="Sudan">Sudan</option><option value="Suriname">Suriname</option><option value="Svalbard">Svalbard</option><option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option><option value="Sweden">Sweden</option><option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option><option value="Syria">Syria</option><option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option><option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option><option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option><option value="Thailand">Thailand</option><option value="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option><option value="Togo">Togo</option><option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option><option value="Tonga">Tonga</option><option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option><option value="Tromelin Island">Tromelin Island</option><option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option><option value="Turkey">Turkey</option><option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option><option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option><option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option><option value="Uganda">Uganda</option><option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option><option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option><option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option><option value="United States">United States</option><option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option><option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option><option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option><option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option><option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option><option value="Virgin Islands">Virgin Islands</option><option value="Wake Island">Wake Island</option><option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option><option value="West Bank">West Bank</option><option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option><option value="Yemen">Yemen</option><option value="Zambia">Zambia</option><option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option></select></td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
</div>

<div id="repeat" class="repeat"></div>

<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td colspan="4" style="text-align:right;">
<input type="submit" value="Book Now!" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

PHP - Action File (book_add.php):

```
<?php 

$numpass = $_POST[numpass];

//Booking Details
$book_cat = $_POST[book_cat]; 
$book_type = $_POST[book_type]; 
$book_pu_loc = $_POST[book_pu_loc]; 
$book_date = $_POST[book_date]; 
$book_time = $_POST[book_time];

//Payment Details
$baseamount = $_POST[baseamount];
$payamount = $_POST[payamount];
$pay_type = $_POST[pay_type];
$payee = $_POST[payee];
$paydisc = $_POST[paydisc];
$extraother = $_POST[extraother];
$extrapick = $_POST[extrapick];

foreach ($_POST['cust_fname'] as $cust_num => $cust_fname) {
}
foreach ($_POST['cust_lname'] as $cust_num => $cust_lname) {
}
foreach ($_POST['cust_kg'] as $cust_num => $cust_kg) {
}
foreach ($_POST['cust_phone'] as $cust_num => $cust_phone) {
}
foreach ($_POST['cust_email'] as $cust_num => $cust_email) {
}
foreach ($_POST['cust_addr_num'] as $cust_num => $cust_addr_num) {
}
foreach ($_POST['cust_addr_street'] as $cust_num => $cust_addr_street) {
}
foreach ($_POST['cust_addr_sub'] as $cust_num => $cust_addr_sub) {
}
foreach ($_POST['cust_addr_state'] as $cust_num => $cust_addr_state) {
}
foreach ($_POST['cust_addr_country'] as $cust_num => $cust_addr_country) {
}
foreach ($_POST['cust_addr_post'] as $cust_num => $cust_addr_post) {
}

print_r (array($cust_fname));

/*

//Insert Customers
$insert_customer = "INSERT INTO heli_cust (cust_fname, cust_lname, cust_kg, cust_phone, cust_email, cust_addr_num, cust_addr_street, cust_addr_sub, cust_addr_state, cust_addr_country, cust_addr_post) VALUES ('$cust_fname', '$cust_lname', '$cust_kg', '$cust_phone', '$cust_email', '$cust_addr_num', '$cust_addr_street', '$cust_addr_sub', '$cust_addr_state', '$cust_addr_country', '$cust_addr_post')";

mysql_query($insert_customer) or die("<table width='100%'><tr><td valign='middle'><img src='images/fail.png'></td><td valign='middle'> - Customer - Unable to insert into database! Error - " .mysql_error(). "</td></tr></table>");

echo "<table width='100%'><tr><td valign='middle'><img src='images/complete.png'></td><td valign='middle'> - Customers - Inserted into Table!</td></tr></table>";
/*
//Insert Booking into Booking Table -- Need: Customer ID Numbers

$customers = "SELECT * FROM heli_cust
ORDER BY cust_id DESC
LIMIT " .$numpass;
$get_customers = mysql_query("$customers") or die ("<table width='100%'><tr><td valign='middle'><img src='images/fail.png'></td><td valign='middle'> - Customer 1 - Unable to insert into database! Error - " .mysql_error(). "</td></tr></table>");


if ($custs = mysql_fetch_array($get_customers)) {
    do {
        if ($custs[cust_id] >0) {
            echo $custs[cust_fname];
        } else {
        }
    } while ($custs = mysql_fetch_array($get_customers));
}

/*

$insert_book = "INSERT INTO heli_book (book_cat, book_type, book_pu_loc, book_date, book_time, book_pax1, book_pax2, book_pax3, book_pax4, book_pax5, book_pax6, book_made_u, book_made_d, book_made_t) VALUES ('$book_cat', '$book_type', '$book_pu_loc', '$book_date', '$book_time', '$cust1id', '$cust2id', '$cust3id', '$cust4id', '$cust5id', '$cust6id', '$user', '$date', '$time')";

mysql_query($insert_book) or die("<table width='100%'><tr><td valign='middle'><img src='images/fail.png'></td><td valign='middle'> - Booking - Unable to insert into database!</td></tr></table>");
?>

Updating...
```

Comment: I believe this requires a button within the form, which I am trying to avoid. I'm looking for a onChange function or equivelent so that when a value (1 - 12) is selected from the Select Element, it clones the div that amount of times.

Answer (score 0):

This is how:

```
$("copy_source_selector").clone().appendTo( "copy_destination_location_selector" );
```

Or any reasonable alternative for .appendTo which will serve your goal, but the copy is created by .clone().

This is what you need to adapt:

```
<body>
    <select onchange="cpyDIV(this.value)">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>

    <div id="passenger">123</div>

    <div id="dest">dest</div>

            <script>

                function cpyDIV(val)
                {
                    $("#dest").empty();

                    for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
                        var $clone = $("#passenger").clone();
                        $clone[0].id += i;
                        $clone.appendTo("#dest");
                    }

                }


            </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Applied, but still only comes back with the value of the last cloned div.

Comment: Where do you read it at php code? (Although I don't know php.)

Comment: Accordingly to this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009436/server-side-doesnt-see-changes-on-client-side I suppose what you should to transfer all cloning functionality to server side to achieve your goal. Sorry man.

Comment: Also you can post all the data of client side created tags to server with ajax and then process it there.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: This is the basic reference: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php Analogically to this you should grab all the relevant data from inside "passenger" tag and format it to JSON, then send it to server php to process, whatever you do there with passengers data. That's the method.